# PHP Convert string to hexadecimal and also the reverse

Tags: php, encoding, hex

I need to convert a string to hexadecimal and am having issues

For example, if I have string 'Geoff', and I call

```
$hex = bin2hex( base64_decode( $fName ) );
```

the output of $hex in console is

```
19ea1f
```

This is obviously incorrect, as it should be exactly 10 characters. Could anyone help me out on this? I've searched all over and tried a couple suggestions but nothing works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `base64_decode`

Is that string encoded before ?I don't think so.

remove `base64_decode` :

```
$hex = bin2hex('Geoff');

var_dump($hex);//string(10) "47656f6666"
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I never would have thought of that because I'm working with some functions that only accept variables in the same format produced by random_bytes( 32 ). These variables break my Chrome console if i don't run bin2hex on them first, and if i run hex2bin after working on them to feed them back into a function, again it breaks console. So i though binary would be something you can't view in console, but obviously if you call bin2hex on a regular string, that also produces a hexadecimal as you say. So how come I can't view random_bytes( 32 ) in my console if i can view 'Geoff'?

Comment: Glad to hear that and don't forget  to accept that answer :)

console breaks means ... unable to see output .. isn't it ?
If yes, need to see your functions to find out exact reason behind this